# If $R$ is a commutative ring with unity and $R$ has only one maximal ideal then show that the equation $x^2=x$ has only two solutions

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

If $R$ is a commutative ring with unity and $R$ has only one maximal ideal then show that the equation $x^2=x$ has only two solutions.

---

I know that $0$ and $1$ are the solutions, but I can't proceed from there.

Comment: The phrasing this question usually occurs in is "A local ring has only trivial idempotents." It's true even for noncommutative local rings, by the same arguments given below. (A noncommutative local ring is one with a unique maximal right ideal, or, equivalently, a unique maximal left ideal.)

Answer (score 6):

Let $M$ be the maximal ideal of $R.$ Then $R= \{ units \} \cup M.$ Now suppose $x(x-1)=0.$ If $x$ is a unit then multiplying by the inverse gives $x=1.$ If $x-1$ is a unit then multiplying by its inverse gives $x=0.$ Thus if $x\neq 0,1$ is to solve $x(x-1)=0$ then $x$ and $x-1$ are both not units, and hence both in $M.$ But then $ 1= x - (x-1)\in M$ which is nonsense.

Comment: could you please explain me "Thus if $x\neq 0,1$ is to solve $x(x-1)=0$ then $x$ and $x-1$ are both not units, and hence both in $M.$ But then $ 1= x - (x-1)\in M$ which is nonsense."

Comment: may be i am not understanding the way u have written the combined sentense as I must confess m weak in understanding english

Comment: @Tsotsi If $x$ is a solution of $x(x-1)=0$ and $x$ is not $0$ or $1$, then $x$ can not be a unit (since if $x$ is a unit, we can solve $x(x-1)=0$ by multiplying both sides by $x^{-1}$ to get $x=1$ ) and $x-1$ can not be a unit (since if $x-1$ is a unit, we can solve $x(x-1)=0$ by multiplying both sides by $(x-1)^{-1}$ to get $x=0$). Since $R = \{ units \} \cup M,$ and $x, x-1$ are both not units, we have $x\in M$ and $x-1\in M.$ Since $M$ is an ideal, it is closed under subtraction, so $x-(x-1)\in M$ so $1\in M.$ But this is a contradiction, since $M$ is a maximal (and hence a proper) ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $r \in R$ satisfies $r^2=r$.  Since $(r)+(1-r)=R$, one of the principal ideals $(r)$ or $(1-r)$ is not contained in the maximal ideal $M$.  But then $(r)=R$ or $(1-r) = R$, i.e. $r$ or $1-r$ is a unit.

If $x$ is a unit satisfying $x^2=x$, then $x=1$ (dividing by $x$).  Thus $r=1$ or $1-r=1$.